# Is there anything special in developing mobile applications in phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

Am a android application developer and am new to phonegap. 
I heard of phonegap framework and my doubt is developing with phonegap have any other advantage than cross platform.
Am going to develop application only for android is there any other special use of phonegap for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, with PhoneGap you write your applications in HTML5 and Javascript and get access to some stuff like GPS, Sensors, etc that you wouldn't get with a "simple" web application running in Mobile Safari or the Android Browser (does that have a special name?).

So, if you do not plan to port your applications to another platform and you already know Java and the Android SDK, there's not a real advantage for you moving to PhoneGap.